# Problema al intentar vaciar y cargar un DataGridView en C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

estoy intentando cargar un DataGridView con un listado de socios que me llegan filtrados, pero al momento de cargar me cargar todos los socios mas los que filtro. No veo donde puede estar el error. El filtro lo aplica mientras se va escribiendo, para explicarme mejor: si ingreso fra me tiene que mostrar todos los socios, cuyo nombre inician con esas 3 letras, como Franco, Francisco, Franca, etc.

El codigo del textBox es el siguiente:

```
private void txt_filtro_nombre_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {       
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_filtro_nombre.Text))
            {
                cargarGrilla(svSocio.getSocioPorNombre(txt_filtro_nombre.Text));
            }
        }
```

El codigo de `getSocioPorNombre(textbox)` que me trae los datos es el siguiente:

```
public IList<DTO_Socio> getSocioPorNombre(string nombre)
        {
            IList<DTO_Socio> lista = new List<DTO_Socio>();
            IList<Socio> listaSocios = dao.getSociosPorNombre(nombre);
            foreach (Socio socio in listaSocios)
            {
                lista.Add(mapSocio.getDtoSocio(socio));
            }

            return lista;
        }
```

el cual se comunica con el DAO que me trae los datos desde la base de datos y tiene este codigo:

```
public IList<Socio> getSociosPorNombre(string nombre)
        {
            string sp = "listar_socios_por_nombre";
            var parametro = new SqlParameter("@nombre", nombre);
            parametro.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;

            IList<Socio> listaSocios = getSocios();
            DataTable tabla = helper.consultarStoredProcedureConUnParametro(sp, parametro);
            foreach (DataRow fila in tabla.Rows)
            {
                listaSocios.Add(mapper(fila));
            }
            return listaSocios;
        }
```

El codigo del helper que se comunica con la base de datos:

```
public DataTable consultarStoredProcedureConUnParametro(string sp, SqlParameter parametro)
        {
            SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            DataTable tabla = new DataTable();

            try
            {
                cnn.ConnectionString = string_conexion;
                cnn.Open();
                cmd.Connection = cnn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = sp;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parametro);
                tabla.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                return tabla;
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("EXPLOTO EL HELPER", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                throw (ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                this.CloseConnection(cnn);
            }
        }
```

El codigo de `cargarGrilla():`

```
dgv_socios.Rows.Clear();
            if (lista != null)
            {
                foreach (DTO_Socio dto in lista)
                {
                    dgv_socios.Rows.Add(new Object[]
                            {
                                dto.NumeroSocio,
                                dto.Nombre,
                                dto.Apellido,
                                dto.Dni
                            }
                        );
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No hay datos para mostrar", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
```

No logro ver donde esta el error, por el cual me trae todos los socios + los filtrados.

Les dejo una imagen de lo que digo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejecute el SP en la base de datos para ver si eso fallaba, pero funciona excelente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Franco, revisando el código que publicaste, hay una instrucción que llamó mi atención en el método `getSociosPorNombre`.

Se trata de la instrucción donde inicializas la variable `listaSocios` y aunque no publicaste el código del método `getSocios()`, por el nombre que tiene supongo que es el responsable de buscar todos los socios.

Esa variable debería ser inicializada con una lista vacía.

```
public IList<Socio> getSociosPorNombre(string nombre)
    {
        string sp = "listar_socios_por_nombre";
        var parametro = new SqlParameter("@nombre", nombre);
        parametro.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;



    //    Sospecho que esta es la línea del problema
    //                              |
    //                              V
        IList<Socio> listaSocios = getSocios();


        DataTable tabla = helper.consultarStoredProcedureConUnParametro(sp, parametro);
        foreach (DataRow fila in tabla.Rows)
        {
            listaSocios.Add(mapper(fila));
        }
        return listaSocios;
    }
```

Comment: Exactamente ese era el problema, por hacer copy-paste, olvide inicializar en null o hacer el new. Muchas gracias, me saque los ojos revisando y nunca vi esa tontera.